# Handle content afler login

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, sammy.js

I am trying to do an single-page app, and I have two types of users. The content (the dashboard) should be rendered depending on the type of user who is logged in.
Now, I am completly new both to laravel and sammy.js and I really have no idea how to handle it.

I think the workflow should be the following:

1. Create a template for the dashboard of each user type
2. User inputs the login credentials, clicks the button
3. Ajax call to a PHP that verifies the credentials and returns whether the user has entered them correctly and the type of user.
4. Ajax gets the response and a new function is called with the parameter `user_type`.Depending on the user type, the right content will be rendered.

Now, my code looks like this:
//app/views/start.php

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" method="post" action="#/login">
      <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

//public/js/myjs.js (renders new content)

```
mtp = (function() {
    var app = null;
    var init = function($) {

    app = $.sammy('#pagecontainer',function() {
        this.use('Template');

    this.get('#/', function(){} );
    this.post('#/submitrequestfrontpage', function(){
        context=this;
        $("#pagecontainer").html('');
        context.render('addlifecircledata.template').appendTo($("#pagecontainer"));
        });
    this.post('#/login',function(){
           //need to put intelligent stuff here
           });
    });

$(function() {
    app.run('#/');
});

};

return {
    init: init
}
})();
```

Although the logic seems to be okay, I don't really know how should I start writing the code. Specifically, how to get the parameters in myjs.js in order to fire the AJAX call and then get the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can either store them in html elements like

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}" />
```

which you will later select with `$('#user_id').val()` in your myjs.js

or you can assign all variables in the header, for example:

```
<head>
    <script>
      var user_id = '{{ $user_id }}';
    </script>
    <script src="myjs.js"></script>
</head>
```